# Ionic run android doesn't load JS Files

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm using yeoman ionic to build and run my ionic.

When I run `grunt run:android`, the app installed on my device, but all the JS and Css files doesn't seems to be loaded.
Here's the logcat. Can anybody help me solve this?

```
D/chromium(27451): request for [file:///styles/vendor.css]failed, restarting..
D/chromium(27451): request for [file:///styles/vendor.css]failed, restarting..
D/chromium(27451): request for [file:///styles/main.css]failed, restarting..
D/chromium(27451): request for [file:///styles/main.css]failed, restarting..
D/chromium(27451): request for [file:///scripts/vendor.js]failed, restarting..
D/chromium(27451): request for [file:///scripts/vendor.js]failed, restarting..
D/chromium(27451): request for [file:///cordova.js]failed, restarting..
D/chromium(27451): request for [file:///cordova.js]failed, restarting..
D/chromium(27451): request for [file:///scripts/scripts.js]failed, restarting..
D/chromium(27451): request for [file:///scripts/scripts.js]failed, restarting..
D/chromium(27451): Unknown chromium error: -6
D/chromium(27451): Unknown chromium error: -6
D/chromium(27451): Unknown chromium error: -6
D/chromium(27451): Unknown chromium error: -6
D/chromium(27451): Unknown chromium error: -6
```

Comment: Start the new project, copy the files.
Works like charm :/